# Push button not able to trigger "event in dialgoflow cx"

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm new to Dialogflow CX, and I'm currently working on creating a chatbot that will operate within Slack, integrated with Dialogflow CX.

I've successfully integrated Slack with Dialogflow, and I can receive responses from Dialogflow. However, I'm facing an issue when attempting to generate custom responses, such as "yes" or "no," using buttons. Despite trying various approaches, I haven't been able to trigger an event in Dialogflow CX when a button is pressed. I would greatly appreciate your assistance with this matter.